# Looping a check user input for matching string?

Tags: ruby

```
def get_input(*options)
  puts "Choose one:"
  options.each do |option|
    puts "#{option}"
  end
  choice = gets.chomp.to_s
  options.each do |option|
    if choice.include?(option.to_s)
    return choice
    end
  end
  puts "Command not found..."
  get_input(options)
end
```

if a user enters an invalid command it puts the available commands again but with the current value including [,]. How would I avoid this.

Comment: Please edit to clarify "current value including `[,]`. I don't understand what "current value" refers to or what you mean by "including `[,]`".

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a splat in the recursive call for `get_input`:

```
  puts "Command not found..."
  get_input(options)
end
```

should be:

```
  puts "Command not found..."
  get_input(*options)
end
```